# MySQL Trigger syntax error unexpected end of input

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers, insert

this is the query that i am using

```
create trigger trig1 after insert on participant for each row
begin
insert into team(sap) select sap from participant order by ID desc limit 1,1
end;
```

it is supposed to copy the sap field from the participant table into the sap field of the team table after a new row is inserted into the participant table
the engine shows me an unexpected end of input error at the end of "end"

i've  tried numerous methods to rework the query but i keep getting the same error
what am i doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: We can't know what you are doing wrong unless you post your code. Please post your relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using trigger than no need to run a query on same table to get latest **sap** value, you can directly get that value using **new.sap**.

**Problem** in your query, In your query you haven't put semicolon(;) after **INSERT..SELECT** query and **END** keyword.

This will work for you:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER /*!50032 IF EXISTS */ `trig1`$$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `trig1` AFTER INSERT ON `participant` 
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO team(sap) 
        VALUES(new.sap);
    END;
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thanks a lot....that worked....actually i did not know what the new keyword was for